# iPad Dead Spot?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an issue with my iPad 4.

Here is a little background.  I recently broke my screen, so I took it to one of those **you break it i fix it** chains and they replaced it and things were working great for a few weeks. However, I ended up taking it back (because a home screen was slightly dented in after the initial fix), so they fixed it yet again, but after that I found a dead spot on the screen.  I took it back, then they called me a few days later claiming they have changed the screen 4 times, but the issue was still persistent, so now they think it may be the motherboard.

I know my questions will be slightly generic, but has anyone heard of dead spot issues being cause by a faulty motherboard?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard about such an issue and I can't imagine about a dead spot caused by the motherboard. Is it just one pixel or a larger spot? What does it looks like?

But I can imagine that the service haven't changed the screen. There were several reports about such "repair services" who've not done their work very well. "Its not the screen its the motherboard" and another service replaced the screen and it worked fine. I wouldn't trust such guys.

Comment: It doesn't look pixelated, it's somewhat small, so I would assume it might be a pixel or two.  At least they offered a refund.

Comment: Maybe an inclusion in the screen? Do you have a magnifier to check it?

Comment: I'll be picking it up tomorrow (or today) and I'll check it out, thanks for the suggestion.